# get e menu with float

Tags: html, css, menu, css-float

I want a menu like this: [menssana.be/FOOD/](http://menssana.be/FOOD/)

But this isn't made with float. When I resize my screen it isn't readable.
So i want to make it with float but I can't get it right.
There is always something wrong.
Can someone give me a few hints

My code is:

```
#active {
    /*  color:#FFFFFF; 
       background-color: #1A1718;  */
}
#menu {
    margin-top: -1%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D3D5D7;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
menu ul {
}
#menu a {
    color:#000000;
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 25px;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1A1718;
}
#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.link {
    width: 11%;
}

  <div id ="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class ="link"><a class ="active" href ="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li class ="link"><a href ="samenstellingen.php">Samenstellingen</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li class ="link"><a href ="panini.php">Panini's</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li class ="link"><a href ="soep.php">Soep</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li class ="link"><a href ="beleg.php">Beleg</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li class ="link"><a href ="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li class ="link"><a href ="../WELNESS/index.php">Schoonheidssalon</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: don't set the width for .link

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your menu isn't readable because is overlapping the elements, then you need to break in a new line when the screen size is too small. Try with this:

```
.link{
  /*width: 11%; Remove this*/
  min-width:11%; /*Include this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every menu item to have equal width, you should go with a display:table as you can see in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAe5k/2/). I have renamed some of your ids/class because [it’s better to style with classes](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/) and cleaned up your code.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="samenstellingen.php">Samenstellingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="panini.php">Panini's</a></li>
    <li><a href="soep.php">Soep</a></li>
    <li><a href="beleg.php">Beleg</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="../WELNESS/index.php">Schoonheidssalon</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #D3D5D7;
    color: #000000;
}
.nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav li + li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.nav a {
    color:#000000;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1A1718;
}
```

But it’s still not perfect on small screens due to the number of items in your menu and the length of the words. So you can decide to change your menu style with [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) on small screens, remove `table-layout: fixed;` to gain readability but loose equal width for items, or reorganize your menu.

Comment: i have already implemented media queries. but just for iphone between 320 and 568px